# How to rewrite a 'select top x subquery' to use joins?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, url-rewriting

I have a query where I use a sub query, and I would like to rewrite into a join, to have better performance. (ms access)

So how do I rewrite a query like this to use join:

```
SELECT t.StudentID, t.subject, t.testid, t.TestScore, t.ID
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE (((t.[TestID]) In (SELECT TOP 2 testid
                         FROM MyTable
                         WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID 
                         AND subject = t.subject
                         ORDER BY TestScore asc, testid)))
ORDER BY t.StudentID, t.TestScore, t.testID;
```

Like Gordon Linoff says, if that cannot easily rewrite into a join syntax, how about a 'not in'?
Is this also hard to rewrite into a join syntax? 
Plus, FYI, I use MS-access.

```
SELECT t.StudentID, t.subject, t.testid, t.TestScore, t.ID
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE t.TestID not In (SELECT TOP 2 testid
                       FROM MyTable
                       WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID 
                       AND subject = t.subject
                       ORDER BY TestScore asc, testid)))
ORDER BY t.StudentID, t.TestScore, t.testID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (easily) rewrite this query to use `join`s.  Instead, you can add indexes.

The best index for this query is `MySQL(StudentId, subject, TestScore, testid)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.